# Replace the value in a row when two columns have specific values

Tags: r

I am lloking for a solution to this problem in R. I have a data frame like this:

```
A1 A2 A3 A4
22  a  1  1
22  b  3  3
21  c  1  2
23  w  1  1
22  a  4  4
```

I look for a way to change the values in `A1` column when `A1` and `A2` have a value of `22` and `a`. In this case when this cristeris is gotten `A1` will have a value of `19`, and the data frame will be like this:

```
A1 A2 A3 A4
19  a  1  1
22  b  3  3
21  c  1  2
23  w  1  1
19  a  4  4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
example <- data.frame(A1=c(22,22,21,23,22),A2=c("a","b","c","w","a"),A3=c(1,3,1,1,4),A4=c(1,3,2,1,4))

example$A1[example$A1==22 & example$A2=="a"] <- 19

> example
  A1 A2 A3 A4
1 19  a  1  1
2 22  b  3  3
3 21  c  1  2
4 23  w  1  1
5 19  a  4  4
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have large data tables, and speed matters, I would recommend data.table. Here is what it would look like.

```
library(data.table)
example <- data.table(example)
setkey(example,A1,A2)
example[J(22,"a"), A1 := 19] #uses binary search, faster than example[A1 ==22 & A2 == "a", A1 := 19]

> example
    A1 A2 A3 A4
1: 19  a  1  1
2: 22  b  3  3
3: 21  c  1  2
4: 23  w  1  1
5: 19  a  4  4
```

Feel free to compare times for the data.frame and data.table solutions on a larger data set.

Comment: +1 With the caveat that that's a vector scan in `i` (usually discouraged). Binary search using `setkey` will perform even better, as per intro vignette.